# Spring MVC @ExceptionHandler does not catch MethodArgumentNotValidException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation, spring-mvc, exception

I wanted to create a registration form where the passed data is observed whether it is valid or not.

Here is my code:

```
@Controller
public class RegistrationController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String registration(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new RegistrationRequest());      
        return "register";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String register(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") RegistrationRequest user,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
        
        String token = userService.registerUser(user);
        response.addHeader("Set-Cookie", token + "; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=Lax;");
        return "index";
    }


    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public String handleIncorrectRequests(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, Model model) {
        String errorFields = ex.getBindingResult()
                .getAllErrors().stream()
                .map(err -> ((FieldError) err)
                .getField())
                .distinct()
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
        String message = String.format("The next fields are incorrectly filled: %s!",
                errorFields);
        
        model.addAttribute("error", "Registration failed");
        model.addAttribute("cause", message);
        return "error";
    }

      @ExceptionHandler(EmailAlreadyInUseException.class)
    public String handleEmailAlreadyInUse(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("error", "Registration failed");
        model.addAttribute("cause", "The given email is already being used! Please try with a different one!");
        return "error";
    }

}
```

Here is the RegistrationRequest's implementation:

```
@Data
@ValidateConfirmPassword
public class RegistrationRequest {
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 4 ,max = 100)
    private String username;
    @NotBlank
    private String email;
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 6)
    private String password;
    
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 6)
    private String confirmPassword;
}
```

The additional validator classes:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = ConfirmPasswordValidator.class)
@Target( { ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidateConfirmPassword {
    String message() default "Confirm password not matches the password!";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

```
public class ConfirmPasswordValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidateConfirmPassword, RegistrationRequest>{

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(RegistrationRequest value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return value.getPassword().equals(value.getConfirmPassword());
    }

}
```

When the data is valid the system does its job, but when any constraint violation happen I get the following log and bad request screen:

```
[36m.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Resolved [org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: ... (list of incorrectly filled fields)
```

I have no clue why the ExceptionHandler does not catch it, while the other one for EmailAlreadyInUseException works properly. Any help would be a blessing.

Comment: It doesn't work because, as you can see in the error, you are handling the wrong exception, it throws a `BindException` and not the specific subclass (it seems).

Comment: Thank you, I changed it to `BindException`  and now it works.